# Mysql put record between two records order

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

here are records and we want move id #1 between #3 & #4

```
id  title   sort
1     a      1
2     b      2
3     c      3
4     d      4
5     e      5
6     f      6
```

**method one :**

get #3 sort number and plus 1 to it and update #1 sort with that so we have

```
id  title   sort
1     a      4
2     b      2
3     c      3
4     d      4
5     e      5
6     f      6
```

and then plus 1 to #4 sort and any records after that

and we have

```
id  title   sort
1     a      4
2     b      2
3     c      3
4     d      5
5     e      6
6     f      7
```

and after sort

```
id  title   sort
2     b      2
3     c      3
1     a      4
4     d      5
6     e      6
6     f      7
```

it works fine but imagine we have 2,000,000 records and all records must be update...

**method two**

get sum sort of #3 and #4 and divide on 2 => (3+4)/2=3.5
and just put it for #1 sort

```
id  title   sort
2     b      2
3     c      3
1     a      3.5
4     d      4
5     e      5
6     f      6
```

it is work fine too but imagine thousand of this operation make big floats like 3.99999999999 and after a while its horrible

is there any mysql/mariadb trick or method for do this ?

Comment: You can use floats and then periodically go into the table and normalize the values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff normalizing big data  , makes mysql down ...

Comment: Please describe the need for such operations.  There may be a totally different approach that works better.

Comment: @RickJames this is for back-end section of a shopping web application ,  in front view user can sort products with drag & drop (angular) and order must save after user drop every product , this is hole back and front projects -> https://github.com/shopiddev

Answer (score 0):

Your "drop it half-way between items" method may be the best.

Let's go with `BIGINT UNSIGNED` since it gives you 64 bits in 8 bytes.  Less good: `DOUBLE` would give you 53 bits in 8 bytes, and some funny business with exponents.  `DECIMAL` gives you more bits at a cost of more bytes, while not eliminating the need for the following code.

- You know which row to put it "after" based on user input?
- Discover the row after by using `ORDER BY ... ASC LIMIT 1`.
- Average the two values; check to see if the avg is equal either of them -- if so, you have a bad case.

Digression...  2M rows.  Start with 2K, 4K, 6K, etc as the `sort` values (2M*2K = 4G, the limit of `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.)

This says you can squeeze 2K items between any adjacent pair.  However, in the worst case of repeatedly inserting exactly after the first value, you get only 11 inserts before hitting the wall.  11 ~= log2(2000).  That is, the re-sort is may be quick, but up to 1 time in 11, it will be costly.

(Please don't quibble between 2K meaning 2000 vs 2048; it does not matter to the algorithm.)

So, what to do when there is no room to insert a new sort value?  Rebuilding the numbers would lock the table (of 2M rows) for "too long", so let's try to avoid that.

How about this:

Grab the 10 rows before and after (2 SELECTs with ORDER BY and LIMIT).  Fix those `sort` values so that they are evenly spread out.

- Possibly no issue with hitting the start or end of the table; it would be less than 20 rows.  And there is a silent 0 and 4G-1 boundaries.
- If the 20 rows are not enough, then broaden the span.
- Do all this (including the original, simple, half-way code) in a transaction.
- Use `FOR UPDATE` on all(?) `SELECTs` so that other threads are blocked.
- Check for deadlocks.  If encountered, start over completely.  (The second try will probably find that the half-way attempt works fine -- because some other thread finished spreading the sort values out.)

Timing:

- The half-way case, even with transaction, will probably take a millisecond or so.
- The more complex case won't take much longer, in spite of locking and updating 20 rows.
- You could probably handle 1K actions per second.